# Laravel testing for compatibility between old and new password-hashing schemes

Tags: php, unit-testing, authentication, laravel

I currently have an event listener tied to Laravel's `Attempting` class. The listener is designed to rehash an old password to something newer. The current DB stores the pass in an old crypt format. I'm just silently converting that old hash to a newer one. This works when going to the site to login. Now I want to be a good developer and get tests down. I have a test made that passes. I am not certain however this is the proper way to test it. I would also like to make sure that passwords are not stored in plain text at any time. I am new to testing so I would like to know if this is correct test to use.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Attempting;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

class PasswordTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;


    /** @test */
    function user_is_able_to_login_with_old_rs_password()
    {
        $user = factory('App\User')->create(['password' => '<old badly used hash>']);

        $response = $this->post('/login',[
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'secret'
        ]);

        $response->assertRedirect('/');
    }

    /** @test */
    function user_password_changed_to_new_hash()
    {
        Event::fake();

        $user = factory('App\User')->create(['password' => '<old badly hashed pass>']);

        $this->post('/login',[
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => 'secret'
        ]);
        Event::assertDispatched(Attempting::class);

        $pw = 'secret';

        $this->assertTrue(Hash::check($pw, $user->password));
        $this->post('/logout');
        $this->post('/login',[
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => $pw
        ]);

        $this->assertFalse(Hash::check($pw, $pw));
    }

}
```

This test does return green.. but I have doubts. I would love any tips or tricks so I can improve.

Comment: If the login mechanism involves transmitting the password to the server, then there is no way to know for sure that the server isn't [storing or logging](https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2019/03/keeping-passwords-secure/) a plaintext copy of the password somewhere, unless you inspect the source code of the server.

Comment: I haven't changed anything changed anything from laravel's default login system, so I'm pretty sure there's no plain text passwords anywhere.. but that link had good reading so I'll be double checking just in case.